# Tabulator 4 - image not showing

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I can't get the image to show. When I look at the source code in the brower, I get an odd link that seem to have some hex code in it.

For e.g. the image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4bW0.png turns into `https:&#x2F;&#x2F;i.imgur.com&#x2F;PQHq7Kb.png`

My tabulator codeblock:

```
 var table = new Tabulator("#adsTable", {
    rowClick:function(e, row){
        data = row.getData();
        console.log(data.image);

},
height:"311px",
layout:"fitDataFill",
responsiveLayout:"hide",
columns:[
{title:"OrderID", field:"OrderID", width:150, responsive:0},
{title:"Plop", field:"Plop", sorter:"number", width:300, responsive: 0},
{title:"Numb", field:"Numb", width:120, responsive:2}, 
{title:"Format", field:"Format", width:150},
{title:"Status", field:"Status", width:150},
{title:"Sidnr", field:"Sidnr", width:150},
{title:"Produkt", field:"Produkt", width:150},
{title:"Kommentar", field:"Kommentar", width:300},
{title: "Img", field: "Img", width: 150, responsive: 0, formatter:"image"},
],});
```

The data Im sending in

```
var tableData = [
{OrderID:1, Plop:"Mary May", Numb:"1", Format:"1/4", Status:2, Sidnr: 1,Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4bW0.png" },
{OrderID:2, Plop:"Mary May", Numb:"1", Format:"1/4", Status:2, Sidnr: 1,Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "" },
{OrderID:3, Plop:"Billy Bob", Numb:"12", Format:"1/2", Status:1, Sidnr: 1, Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "" },
{OrderID:4, Plop:"Mary May", Numb:"1", Format:"1/8", Status:2, Sidnr: 1, Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "https://i.imgur.com/Bu5tkat.png" },
{OrderID:5, Plop:"Billy Bob", Numb:"12", Format:"Helsida", Status:1, Sidnr: 1, Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "https://i.imgur.com/Bu5tkat.png" },
{OrderID:6, Plop:"Mary May", Numb:"1", Format:"Helsida", Status:2, Sidnr: 1, Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "https://i.imgur.com/Bu5tkat.png" },
{OrderID:7, Plop:"Billy Bob", Numb:"12", Format:"Helsida", Status:1, Sidnr: 1, Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "https://i.imgur.com/Bu5tkat.png" },
{OrderID:8, Plop:"Mary May", Numb:"1", Format:"Helsida", Status:2, Sidnr: 1, Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "https://i.imgur.com/Bu5tkat.png" },
{OrderID:9, Plop:"Billy Bob", Numb:"12", Format:"Helsida", Status:1, Sidnr: 1, Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "https://i.imgur.com/Bu5tkat.png" },
{OrderID:10, Plop:"Mary May", Numb:"1", Format:"Helsida", Status:2, Sidnr: 1, Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "https://i.imgur.com/Bu5tkat.png" },
{OrderID:11, Plop:"Billy Bob", Numb:"12", Format:"Helsida", Status:1, Sidnr: 1, Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "https://i.imgur.com/Bu5tkat.png" },
{OrderID:12, Plop:"Mary May", Numb:"1", Format:"Helsida", Status:2, Sidnr: 1, Produkt: "Kycklingfest", Kommentar: "Internt lagt för någonannans skull. Eller nått. LOL", Img: "https://i.imgur.com/Bu5tkat.png" },]
```

Anybody with an good eye that can spot what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have found a bug there, the url was being sanitized for some reason.

I have pushed a fix for this to the master branch and will include it in the next patch release.

Thanks for letting me know